# Anybody have experience in hanging a huge clock?

Tags: mounting, drywall-anchor

I need help with hanging this giant clock on the wall. Its huge and heavy. I believe its 4-5' in diameter and it weighs about 160 pounds. I figured building some sort of brace for it would be best as I'd like to be able to hit every stud possible. Anybody have any experience with this or know of any pre-made mounts that would work for it? I've thought about getting a heavy duty tv mount but I'm not sure. Any help would be great, thanks[image: ![giant clock]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsdC1.jpg)

Comment: Dang, that's big!

Comment: You should fix the slope in the floor before the clock rolls over you. ☺

Comment: Do you plan on using the large  "eye-bolt" that appears to be at about the 11 o'clock position? Assuming there is a corresponding bolt at the 1 o'clock position.

Comment: What does the back look like?

Comment: The eye-bolt inclines me to think it's meant to be hung from a chain like a giant's pocket watch.

Answer (score 7):

For large heavy objects that you want to span multiple studs, I like a french cleat. You can buy them out of metal from the store, or make your own by ripping a board at 45 degrees along it's length.

[image]

Screw in the wall part to each stud with a long screw or lag bolt, and get either a counter sunk or flush head. And on the back of the clock, you can use lots of short screws that won't come through the face. When hanging, the two boards overlap to hold in place. For added security, you can install a single screw at the bottom of the clock into a stud to prevent it from being lifted up or away from the wall.

Comment: +1 Or the large TV mount the OP suggested. Many TV mounts function exactly like a metal French cleat. And they usually have a built in locking mechanism. But BMitch's has the benefit of being infinitely adjustable in size and usually cheaper. I would use hardwood for the French cleat.

Comment: I think a cleat might reduce the gap from the wall better than a TV mount, for a closer shadow on the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming two eye bolts, one 5/16 lag into a stud and a suitable chain should be more than sufficient, as suggested by @BrownRedHawk. 1/4 really would do, but I prefer a *little* overbuilding.

[A lag screw loading chart](http://countryplans.com/smf/index.php?topic=5268.0) *from countryplans.com, whoever they are (just what I found in search, not affiliated in any way...)* Shear (the main loading mode you'd have) listed at 272 pounds for 1/4", 368 pounds for 5/16, 432 pounds for 3/8

Comment: +1 But note the embedded length - at least 2" in the stud (not counting the drywall and the chain or eyelet). And all bets are off if the studs are steel.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are two eye screws at the top edge for hanging. If that's the case, 3/8" or 7/16" lag screws into framing would do nicely, or some other heavy steel hook or anchor.

The eye screws appear to possibly be at 32" centers. That would allow you to hit two studs on standard layout. If that's not the case, and you won't hit wall plates or other horizontal framing members, you'll need to provide embedded or surface-mount backing for the lag screws.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the eye bolts are purely cosmetic. The back of the clock is just like the front, it's about 4" thick so I'm not worried about drilling through it. Thank you for the comments this was very helpful! I'll post an update when it's on the wall.